# Optimizing Python floodfill function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a gap removal in a 2D array of numbers, but the code runs slowly (3-3.5 sec) and I wanted to make it quicker (<1 sec)

```
    spots = ((-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0))
    def floodFill(x, y):

        global cells

        que = []
        area = []
        areaType = cells[x][y]

        que.append([x, y])

        while len(que) > 0:
            area.append(que[0])
            for spot in spots:
                X = que[0][0] + spot[0]
                Y = que[0][1] + spot[1]

                if -1 < X < width and -1 < Y < height:
                    if cells[X][Y] == areaType:
                        if not [X, Y] in que and not [X, Y] in area:
                            que.append([X, Y])

            que.pop(0)

        return area, areaType
```

I have tried everything I can think of and need help. Thanks!

Comment: Since your code already works fine, wouldn't http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ actually be the appropriate place to get feedback?

Comment: It is also difficult to optimize “working” code when it is not a [mcve] and doesn’t work for us.

Comment: here is a tip:   x in list is O(n), x in set is O(1)

Comment: You're just creating a small structure and defining a function. That should finish **instantly**, not take seconds.

Comment: @superbrain It depends on the size of the 2D `cells` array, which isn't specified.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yeah... my point is that they should give us some data and the call.